# Is it permitted to claim a deduction on income taxes for charitable donations?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah

I would like to know if it is permitted to claim a deduction on income taxes for charitable donations.

For example, United States tax laws allow for income deductions to be claimed for donations to non-profit, charitable organizations designated as 501(c)(3).  Most Islamic charities within the US present their non-profit status and provide their Tax ID numbers as additional evidence of this. Many other countries throughout the world, including predominantly Muslim countries, have similar laws.

I have heard that tax deductions for charitable donations can be considered haram as it provides a benefit to the donor.  In addition, I have found links online both for and against claiming tax deductions for charitable donations.

Is it permissible? Are there different rules regarding this for zakat and sadaqah?